# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller - one pr. environment?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster in Azure. In this i have three namespaces:

1. development
2. staging
3. production

I have installed nginx ingress controller into its own namespace, ingress-nginx. I am kind of new to the ingress part, and I cant seem to find anywhere any advice if I should have a controller pr namespace, or share one controller with all.

Should I have one that is shared or install one pr. namespace? What is the pattern here?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest at least one for production and one for npe.  The nginx-ingress helm chart appears to only support setting a scope to all namespaces or just one namespace (a frustrating limitation not in other ingress controller options):

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress

`controller.scope.namespace`

Comment: Or simply don't use helm, it's really simple to deploy ingress-nginx without it.